# Send Textbox name to function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I made a userform consisting of several modules with a similar code structure. With four of them having the same starting procedure, I tried to replace it with a set of functions.

Userform with set of pictures
[image]

The goal of the form is to arrange a set of pictures according to the user's will. By filling the textbox text the 'pictures per set', you tell how many pictures there are per row. The other commands are self explanatory. The form works as long as the needed boxes are filled.

I wanted to create a function that returns the value from the according box and sends a message if there is no value written. I tried to do this by checking the name of the box, but all I get is '*Invalid Qualifier*'.

```vb
Function check(value As String)
Dim v As Integer

If value = Empty Then
    Select Case value.Name
    
        Case Is = TxtB_Pictures
            MsgBox ("give the number of pictures per set")
        Case Is = TxtB_R1
            MsgBox ("give the first row")
        Case Is = TxtB_R2
            MsgBox ("give the second row")
        Case Is = TxtB_C1
            MsgBox ("give the first column")
        Case Is = TxtB_C2
            MsgBox ("give the second column")
     
Else
    v = CInt(value)
End If

check = v

End Function
```

Here's one of the subs.

```vb
Private Sub CMB_Sort_Click()

Dim S As Shape, r, c, x, y, z, a, b, dAR, T, Ttl, sp As Integer
Dim Ar() As Integer
Dim h, h1, w, w1 As Double
Dim rAr(1 To 99) As Integer
Dim cAr(1 To 99) As Integer

Dim ws As Worksheet

'rename the pictures
x = 1
For Each S In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    S.Name = "Picture " & x
    x = x + 1
Next S

dAR = detect
sp = starting_position

'starting positions
r = sp + 2
c = 2
b = 1
'current pictures placed within set'
a = 0

T = check(TxtB_Pictures.value)

For Each S In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    h = S.Height / 2
    w = S.Width / 2
    h1 = h - w
    w1 = h1

    If a = 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture " & b).Top = ActiveSheet.Rows(r).Top
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture " & b).Left = ActiveSheet.Columns(c).Left
    
        c = c + Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(dAR / 3, 0)

    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture " & b).Top = ActiveSheet.Rows(r).Top
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture " & b).Left = ActiveSheet.Columns(c).Left

        c = c + Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(dAR / 3, 0)

    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("picture " & b).Rotation = 90 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture " & b).IncrementLeft h1
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture " & b).IncrementTop -h1
    End If

    a = a + 1
    b = b + 1

    'all pictures in set placed, go to next row and back to the first column'
    If a = T Then
        r = r + dAR
        c = 2
        a = 0
    End If
    
Next S

End Sub
```

Comment: Your function is wrong, but before correcting it where from do you like calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try using the next updated function. It receives as argument the control itself:

```
Function check(ctrl As msforms.Control) As Integer
Dim v As Integer

If ctrl.value = "" Then
    Select Case ctrl
    
        Case TxtB_Pictures
            MsgBox ("give the number of pictures per set")
        Case TxtB_R1
            MsgBox ("give the first row")
        Case TxtB_R2
            MsgBox ("give the second row")
        Case TxtB_C1
            MsgBox ("give the first column")
        Case TxtB_C2
            MsgBox ("give the second column")
    End Select
Else
   v = CInt(ctrl.value)
End If

check = v

End Function
```

It can be called in the next way:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim ctrlVal As Integer
    ctrlVal = check(Me.TxtB_Pictures) 'use here the control you need/wont
     If ctrlVal > 0 Then
          MsgBox ctrlVal
          'do watever you need with it...
     End If
End Sub
```

I answer your question as it was formulated, but I cannot imagine how you try using/calling it. I asked a clarification question about that, in a comment...

Comment: Sorry got called away for work. ty for your help, it works now. it gets called at T = check(TxtB_Pictures.value) in this private sub. I understand what you've added and did the necessary changes. Only thing i don't fully get is the 'Me' keyword. What does this do? I checked microsoft documentation, but still don't get it.

Comment: @K9506  `Me` keyword behaves like an implicitly declared variable. It is valid in all the class procedures. When I said `class` it may be a Sheet module, a Userform Module etc. In this context it is the equivalent of that specific UserForm object. It is useful when you write the code. It is  **not needed to exactly remember the control name**, anymore. Just write `Me.` and automatically intellisense will bring all the properties of the form in discussion. Start typing `Me.TxtB_P` and it will automatically bring `TxtB_Pictures` to be chosen. After  `Me.TxtB_` it offers all possibilities...

Comment: @K9506 Besides that, I will also like to specify that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the provided solution works...